# single origin policy getting in my way when using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Here's my situation -- I have an account on a site that allows API access. So, theoretically, I could write a program to query the site via its API. I would like to build a local html page using javascript, that shows some results returned from an API call to this site.

My first impulse was to use XMLHttpRequest, which won't return anything from the site -- a known problem due to the single origin policy.

I have no control over what the API returns -- it's XML or nothing.

I would very much like to keep my solution simple -- just HTML and javascript, no php, asp, c# or any of the rest of the alphabet soup of potential technologies out there. I'm also not running my own web server.

Is this even possible? Is there some simple solution I've overlooked?

(I should note here that I'm not trying to hack a website -- i've already got a legitimate account there, and they give me access to the data on the site via their API. I'm just trying to show their data in a more interesting way on my local machine.)

Answer (score 0):

If the Web Service API you are trying to hit does not except a JSONP request or does not implement Cors headers then the only option is to create a Web Service of your own that is either on the same origin of your website or implements JSONP or Cors headers which will be used to hit the the Web Service with the desired data you are looking for. This is a very common problem when interacting with web services these days.

Answer (score 0):

If API doesn't provide jsonp, or is not CORS enabled, there is one other javascript option and that's Yahoo's YQL service. It uses server proxy to get data in multiple formats including scraping html using Xpath selectors, grabbing xml or json or csv and returning data in either xml, json or jsonp  format.

This means with javascript you get get data from virtually any API

[YQL console link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+%2a+from+json+where+url=%22http://ip.jsontest.com/%22+)